# Php echo whitespace from jquery.load

Tags: php, jquery, load

I'm using some jquery/php to update a number when called through .load() function.

so lets say i have

```
<span id='draftCount'>1 Draft</span>
```

And the jquery I call to update it

```
$('#draftCount').load('countItems.php?cid=draftCount');
```

Now the inside of countItems.php

```
<?
    include("connect.php");
mysql_select_db ("news");

$countWhat = $_GET['cid'];

if($countWhat   == 'binCount') {
    $pullBin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bin");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($pullBin);
    echo '$count';
}

if($countWhat   == 'draftCount') {
    $pullBin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   `main`  WHERE   `active` < '2'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($pullBin);
    if ($count ==   '1') $drafts = 'Draft';
    if ($count !=   '1') $drafts = 'Drafts';
    $count = "$count $drafts";
    echo "$count";
}

?>
```

The result is

```
<span id="draftCount">





 4 Drafts</span>
```

How do I get rid of all that whitespace above '4 Drafts'? What's causing it?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably have whitespace inside countItems.php, before the opening `<?`.

Comment: I've added the full contents of countItems.php to the original post. The <? sits on the first line of the page.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found the problem in an connect file i was including. It had the whitespace, and I never noticed :O   Thanks again!

Comment: completely unrelated: why     if ($count ==   '1') $drafts = 'Draft';
    if ($count !=   '1') $drafts = 'Drafts'; instead of : if ($count == 1) $drafts = 'Draft'; } else { $drafts = 'Drafts'; } ?

Comment: Good question. Not what sure what I think when I wrote that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trim function in javascript if you want, but I think that Pekka is probably right.  Better to just not return whitespace.

You could also modify your response to return a json object with that text as a value.  It won't matter if there is whitespace before the declaration of the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant but you can trim the result on the client if you have no access to the server script. Example:

```
$.get("countItems.php?cid=draftCount", function(data) {
    $('#draftCount').html($.trim(data));
});
```

By the way, the whitespace on server-side script result may occur from:

- There actually is a whitespace before the interpreted part of the script
- utf8 with BOM is used
- server software is buggy (use apache with no modules if none of the above works)